# Query usando operador like

Tags: sql

Numa consulta no banco de dados eu informo as palavras chaves, o mês e ano. Quero pegar os dados de acordo as palavras chaves, o mês e o ano. Por exemplo: a palavra **escola** na data **2015-08**.

Para isso, uso o operador `like` ao invés de `=` porque a data está completa e eu quero fazer a pesquisa por mês num determinado ano. A mesma coisa serve para a palavra chave, porque posso ter outras palavras além da palavra **escola** no registro.

**A query é:**

```
select * from despesas where palavraChave like "%escola%" or data like '2015-08%'
```

**O erro é:**

Se eu não passar nenhuma data e nenhuma palavra, ele me traz os dados e eu não quero. Só quero os dados se um dos campos forem encontrados. Já usei `!null`, `!notnull`, coisas do tipo, mas não resolve.

A linguagem é sql e a linguagem do servidor é php.

Comment: Qual é banco de dados, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle. Edite sua pergunta informando isso. Outra questão: o campo data é de que tipo?

Comment: Seu campo data é que tipo ? Varchar, Datetime ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE palavraChave LIKE '%escola%' AND Month(Data) = 8 AND Year(Data) = 2015`

Comment: Faça a verificação se as variáveis possuem valor ou não antes de executar a query.

Answer (score 3):

1)Faça a verificação se as variáveis possuem valor ou não antes de executar a query.

2)Caso não seja possível fazer a verificação faça o seguinte sql

`select * from despesas where (palavraChava like "%escola%" and "%escola%" <> "%%") or (data like '2015-08%' and '2015-08%' <> '%')`

Explicando melhor:

onde eu coloquei `"%escola%" <> "%%"` é porque imagino que a forma que você monta o sql é a seguinte:
`palavraChave like "%{variavel}%"` logo se a variável não estiver preenchida o trecho irá ficar `"%%" <> "%%"`.

A mesma lógica segue para o campo data.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem o que você precisa, tente essa query.

`SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE palavraChave LIKE '%escola%' AND Month(Data) = 8 AND Year(Data) = 2015`

Nunca vi fazer `LIKE` em campo data a não ser que seja `varchar`. Mas mesmo assim, trabalhar com data em campo `varchar` só dá bagunça.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode sim usar `LIKE` para recuperar uma data no seu banco de dados pois `DATETIME` ou `DATE` são *strings*, embora seja mais correto usar os comandos usados acima pelos outros.

Você só precisa fazer assim

```
SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE palavraChave LIKE '%escola%' OR data LIKE '%2015-08%';
```

Você precisa usar o símbolo de `%` antes do ano e depois do mês ou se quiser somente o mês, use antes e depois do mês MAS nesse caso você precisaria fazer `LIKE '%-08-%'`, colocar os - antes e depois do mês, senão corre risco dele pegar dia e anos que contenham esse valor.

Dessa forma ele pega somente o mês.

> Não precisa usar aspas duplas em campos de texto, aspas simples é o mais correto e mais usado.
>
> Se você usar o `OR`, ele vai te devolver tudo que tiver palavra chave escola e qualquer data e tudo que tiver data de Agosto de 2015 e qualquer palavra chave, então se for pra fazer uma pesquisa assim, seria mais fácil usando somente a data ou palavra chave.

```
`SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE palavraChave LIKE '%escola%';`
```

ou
   `SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE data LIKE '%2015-08%';`

Ambos os `SELECTS` retornarão exatamente a mesma coisa que a sua query.

Acredito que você queira que a sua query retorne os dados onde a palavra chave seja escola e a data seja Agosto de 2015. Dessa forma, use o `AND`

```
`SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE palavraChave LIKE '%escola%' AND data LIKE '%2015-08%';`
```

Comment: Não seria mais "certinho" usar um BETWEEN ... AND ... ?

Comment: Não, BETWEEN seria para datas entre X e Y, ele quer apenas X (mês específico).

Comment: Sim, mas poderia ser entre 1/Ago e 31/Ago, certo? Claro que aí envolve calcular o último dia do mês, que é um saco

Comment: Sim, ai poderia usar 

`SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE (data BETWEEN '2015-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-08-31 23:59:59')` 

Desse jeito é mais trabalhoso mas funciona. Sinais de < e > também funcionam.

Comment: É, poderia ser usando between. Não pensei nisso. Vou testar todas soluções apresentadas.

Answer (score 0):

Analizando seu query:

```
select * from despesas where palavraChave like "%escola%" or data like '2015-08%'
```

Você está dizendo ao SQL:

> Por favor, me dá todos os recordes da tablea *despesas*, onde a *palavraChave* é como "escola" não importando a data, OU onde a *data* é como '2015-08' não importando a palavraChave.

Ou seja, está pedindo demais - usando o `AND`, assim:

```
select * from despesas where palavraChave like '%escola%' AND data like '2015-08%'
```

Você está dizendo:

> Por favor, me dá todos os recordes da tabela despesas, onde a palavraChave é como "escola" e a despesa tem a data aparecido com "2015-08". Os demais (recordes com outra palavraChave e outros em outro data) são excluidos.

#### SqlFiddle

[Aqui está um SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/682e0/3) para demonstrar a diferença - use um `OR` e depois use um `AND` e *Run SQL* para ver a diferença.