# Consulta com LIKE no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Como posso fazer uma consulta MySQL que busque apenas resultados que comecem com números e caracteres especiais, eu sei que isso é feito com o **LIKE**, mas eu ainda não sei como obter esse resultado...

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts
WHERE account_name LIKE '(qualquer caractere especial)%', LIKE '(qualquer número)%';
```

Comment: Aqui já tem uma resposta, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80793/query-usando-operador-like

Comment: até ai eu sei, mas eu quero pega apenas os nomes que comecem com caracteres especiais e que comecem com números também

Comment: cite exemplos? quais caracteres especiais?

Comment: É qualquer caractere especial seguido de qualquer coisa tipo "(qualquer caractere especial)%" e números também, por exemplo "(qualquer número)%"

Comment: Tente: `REGEXP_LIKE(seu_campo, '^[^A-Z].+') = 0`.

Comment: consegui obter o resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui obter o resultado através de um REGEXP:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts
WHERE account_name RLIKE "^[^A-Z].+";
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isso pode ajudar:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account_name LIKE '7%TERAÇÃO%'; // COMEÇA COM N°

SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account_name LIKE 'Ç%TERAÇÃO%'; // COMEÇA COM CARACTER ESPECIAL
```